# How to enable circle symbol as slide transition symbol on the header of LatexBeamer

Tags: latex

Does anyone knows how to enable the circle symbol (slide transition) in the beamer theme Darmstadt such as http://www.maths.dundee.ac.uk/~dfg/icms09/beamer-handout.pdf

Thanks.

-jo

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `outer theme` to `berlin`.

```
\useoutertheme{berlin}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the `Darmstadt` theme in combination with the `seahorse` colour theme. It's easy to see that this is not `Berlin` because the the corners of the blocks are round, the inner elements of the slides (enumeration symbols etc.) are also round and the shadow below the headline is also missing in `Berlin`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\title{text}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item test
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```